# Turn a String into class variable name

Tags: python, dictionary, variables

My problem is the following: I've created, in Python, a class let's imagine it is a character with stats, level etc ...

I've also created a dictionary in which are lists all the character name and stats, the key of the dictionary being the name of the character.

I want to create a function that takes in argument the dictionary and that create the characters as an instance of my class. The problem is that i don't know how to give the character name to my variable, i only have the string corresponding to his name by collecting the key.

Example :

```
class Character():
       def __init__(self,Name,Age):
                self.Nom=Name
                self.Age=Age


List_Character= {"Roger" : 36, "Kimberley" : 98}
```

How can I create a function that takes List_Character and return two instance of Character which variable name are Roger and Kimberley ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
class Character():
       def __init__(self,Name,Age):
                self.Nom=Name
                self.Age=Age
                
       def __repr__(self):
           return f"{self.__class__.__name__}(Name={self.Nom}, Age={self.Age})"


List_Character= {"Roger" : 36, "Kimberley" : 98}

def create_instance(cls, params: dict):
    ret = ()
    for k,v in params.items():
        globals()[k] = cls(k, v)
        ret = ret + (globals()[k],)
    return ret

>>> create_instance(Character, List_Character)
(Character(Name=Roger, Age=36), Character(Name=Kimberley, Age=98))

>>> Roger
Character(Name=Roger, Age=36)

>>> Kimberley
Character(Name=Kimberley, Age=98)
```

While the `__repr__` method is not strictly necessary, the code would work all the same without it, it just gives better representations.

The function can be shortened/optimized using [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap):

```
from itertools import starmap
def create_instance(cls, params: dict):
    keys, vals = params.keys(), tuple(starmap(cls, params.items()))
    globals().update(dict(zip(keys, vals)))
    return vals
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to iterate over your dict and create new characters from them, append them to a list and return this list:

```
class Character():
       def __init__(self,Name,Age):
                self.Nom=Name
                self.Age=Age


List_Character= {"Roger" : 36, "Kimberley" : 98}

def create_characters(char_dict):
    return_list = []
    for k,v in char_dict.items():
        return_list.append(Character(k,v))
    return return_list

print(create_characters(List_Character)[0].Nom, create_characters(List_Character)[0].Age)
```

returns:

```
Roger 36
```

I assumed by "return two instances" you meant for example a list with all instances in there, right? Since I guess you don't only want to have it for 2 instances, but rather as many as there are in the dict you use as input.

#Edit:
If you want to access the characters by their name you can use a dict for that:

```
def create_characters(char_dict):
    return_dict = dict()
    for k,v in char_dict.items():
        return_dict[k] = Character(k,v)
    return return_dict

dict_of_chars = create_characters(List_Character)
print(dict_of_chars["Roger"].Age)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Yes, if my dictionary had 1000 characters, I'd like to have 1000 variables that have the same name as the character name. If i've well understood the function returns a list that contains a character, but here the variable name are the index in the list and not the name of the character. I'd like to have print(Roger.Age) For example

Comment: Well this won't work, you could return a dict, such that you can access the characters by name again - e.g. `dict_of_chars["roger"].Age`. Or you say `Roger = list_of_chars[0]` and then you can use `Roger.Age`. But this doesn't make sense if you have 1000 characters, right?